# Obtain the JournalArticle URL

Tags: url, liferay, portlet

I need to send by email the link of the contents in a custom Portlet in Liferay.

How can I obtain the URL for every content my portlet shows?
It possible to make it in the view or have to be an Action to create the URL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can create `renderURL` for every content on the view of your portlet.

Comment: Maybe i explain my problem wrong. I have already the view for the content. My need is create a link to this page because a I have to send the link via email. The asset publisher OOB have this funcionality and i need to replicate it. If you open a content in an asset, on the right side, there is a link to send by email, that's is the link i need to create

Comment: Okay, let me have a look on it. Will update you soon.

Comment: There isn't any link appearing for email. Is there any configuration option to show / hide email link?

Comment: No, there isn't. I've just added an asset with Abstract ADT to display. I've openend any contend on the right side appears a box with the number of views of the content and below a link with a "mailto:..."

Answer (score 1):

"The link of content" does not really map to Liferay concepts: You have content and that content can be displayed on any number of pages. You can either try to find one page where the content is displayed, or (for Web Content) use the "Content Display Page" which chooses a particular page as the context for this article.

If you are using a custom ADT, you might want to add it to your question, so that we know what you're talking about. If it's too long, feel free to simplify it.

Comment: Thanks Olaf, finally i understood the problem. Im searching another solution.